# Is it possible to link Google Drive and Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, google-drive-api

Is there any API that can link Google Drive and Google Plus - to simplify the question, is it allowed for any circle member to see someone's files shared in Google Plus without any explicit uploader consents?

Also, when profile (such as about me) changes, does this change get shown to others without others entering someone's profile?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who you are sharing changes with, specifically which circles. From the [faq](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664693) regarding sharing Google drive documents:

> Select a circle or type the name of individual people you'd like to share your post with.

A profile change is not broadcast to users (as far as I can tell), nor does it ask you to share.